# How can I make a parent component be the label of its child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a library that renders a certain button to my layout. This is the library [`react-add-to-calendar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-add-to-calendar).

I don't have any customization options, so I am currently wrapping the button in a div that gives the button the look that I want. The problem is though, that the child component only takes a very small portion of the parent component, and only the child component reacts to the click.
So for the user, there's a button, that most of it is unclickable, even though it looks like it should be. Only clicking on the text itself sparks the desired action.

How can I make the whole button react appropriately to the click?

This is my code:

```
   <div className="stream__button stream__button-line clickable">
      <AddToCalendar event={event} />
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML end up looking like? You can probably do this very easily with some CSS.

Comment: @segFault How do I check that? I'm new to React.js/Javascipt/HTML. If I go to check the page resource it just shows me the content of my original index.html which is not much at all (nothing to do with this code I am dealing with)

Comment: When you are viewing the page in browser. Right click the div -> Inspect Element. From there right click the `div.stream__button.stream__button-line.clickable` and got to Copy -> Copy the Outer HTML. Paste the HTML in your question. Or if you know what the HTML element `AddToCalendar` renders as that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/jasonsalzman/react-add-to-calendar/blob/master/docs/ReactAddToCalendar.md) you can pass custom classes with the following props:

- `buttonClassClosed`
- `buttonWrapperClass`
- `buttonClassOpen`
- `dropdownClass`
- `rootClass`

Comment: Thank you Muhammed! I haven't figured it our yet but getting there. `buttonClassClosed` seems to be the one that actually wraps the button itself. I'm dealing with otehr issues with it, but it's the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Muhammed! I haven't figured it our yet but getting there. `buttonClassClosed` seems to be the one that actually wraps the button itself. I'm dealing with otehr issues with it, but it's the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, feel free to ask if you encounter any problems :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this.

```
<AddToCalendar event={event} rootClass="stream__button stream__button-line clickable" />
```

and remove the outer div you have now.

You can try `buttonWrapperClass` if `rootClass` is not working.